# dijkstra_sp runs without error in postgres query terminal, but triggers an error in Java

Tags: postgis, pgrouting, java, error

I am running this simple query

```
select id,gid from dijkstra_sp('roads',22,33)
```

This works perfectly fine and returns results in postgres query terminal. However running exactly the same query in java triggers the error:

> org.postgresql.util.PSQLException:
>   ERROR: type "geoms" does not exist
>   Where: compilation of PL/pgSQL function "dijkstra_sp" near line 6

Could anyone tell me how to solve this issue?

yours sincerely.

Comment: For some reason the error was not posted. The error is: <org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: type "geoms" does not exist
  Where: compilation of PL/pgSQL function "dijkstra_sp" near line 6>

Answer (score 1):

I figure out what I was doing wrong. I needed to add the datatypes to the connection so that postgres jdbc driver understands the new datatypes. Simply I added

((org.postgresql.PGConnection)SQLConnectionOBJ ).addDataType("box3d",PGbox3d.class);
((org.postgresql.PGConnection)SQLConnectionOBJ ).addDataType("geoms",PGgeometry.class);

and it worked like charm. Thank you sanak for your answer.

Answer (score 0):

I am not familiar with JDBC PostgreSQL driver,
but it seems that JDBC driver compile PL/pgSQL function at runtime,
and another type("geoms") compiling is fail.

If you want to get the same result, try the following plain query instead of above query.

```
SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER()::integer AS id, gid 
    FROM shortest_path(
        'SELECT gid AS id,
            source::integer,
            target::integer,
            length::double precision AS cost
            FROM roads',
         22, 33, false, false), roads
    WHERE edge_id = gid;
```